# actionscript 3 presentation onclick without buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, presentation

Is there a possibility to go to the next slide with left click, I can only see buttons in the default one right to go forward and left to go backwards. is this possible with the left click to go forward? without any buttons?

This is the default code:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_changeSlide);
function fl_changeSlide(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(evt.keyCode == 37) // LEFT
    {
    gotoAndStop(this.currentFrame-1);
    }
    else if (evt.keyCode == 39 || evt.keyCode == 32) // RIGHT OR SPACE
    { 
        gotoAndStop(this.currentFrame+1);
    }
}stop();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked it out.

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Test);

function Test(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(this.currentFrame+1);
}stop();
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: You can simply do `nextFrame();`   this goes to the next frame and stops the playhead.  `prevFrame();` goes the other direction

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_changeSlide); 
> function fl_changeSlide(evt:KeyboardEvent):void {
> if(evt.keyCode == 37) // LEFT
> {
> gotoAndStop(this.currentFrame+1);
> }
> else if (evt.keyCode == 39 || evt.keyCode == 32) // RIGHT OR SPACE
> { 
>     gotoAndStop(this.currentFrame-1);
> } }stop();
> ```

Comment: this is still only key board presses, is there not an option for left mouse click to go forward or backwards without using buttons?

Comment: stage.addEvevtListener(MouseEvent.Click, fl_changeSlide);